# Should I Use Async Processing?

Tags: c#, service, asynchronous, web

I've got a Windows service that monitors a table (with a timer) for rows, grabs rows one at a time when they appear, submits the information to a RESTful web service, analyzes the response, and writes some details about the response to a table.  Would I gain *anything* by making this async?  My current (stripped down) web service submission code is as follows:

```
HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(new Uri(url));
HttpWebResponse resp;
try
{
      resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
}
catch (WebException we)
{
      resp = (HttpWebResponse)we.Response;
}

if (resp != null)
{
      Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream();
      if (respStream != null)
      {
           responseBody = new StreamReader(respStream).ReadToEnd();
      }

      resp.Close();
      respStream.Close();
}

return responseBody;
```

Comment: If you don't have to do something at the same time and since the user is uninvolved, definitely not. Since it's a service, another thread can accomplish any other activity required.

Comment: It might help to get a more thorough answer if you can detail a few specifics: what's the typical quantity of records you will need to process in x amount of time? What's your program flow? (Meaning, do you pull one record, fire off the request, wait for the response, update the DB, get the next record, repeat; or do you have some other flow?)

Comment: Unless your windows service is really busy doing other stuff and you don't want it waiting for a response, I don't really see any value in making this async. 

On the other hand, I should point out that WebResponse (and thus HttpWebResponse), Stream, and StreamReader all implement IDisposable and ought to be disposed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't care how long it takes to get your response for any individual request, no, there's no particular reason to make it async.

On the other hand, if you're waiting for one request to fully finish before you start your next request you might have trouble handling a large volume. In this scenario you might want to look at parallelizing your code. But that's only worth discussing if you get large numbers of items entered into the database for processing.

Comment: How so? If he has a client that connects to DB, gets a new row and fires off a request to the remote service, waits for the response and saves it to the database, then gets the next row - this is not a parallel process. It might help to have the program flow detailed for us. EDIT - I swear there was a comment I was replying to - now I look like a weirdo!

Comment: Thanks to everyone for their input.  This is the kind of information I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

By using asynchronous methods you avoid the need to have a dedicated thread blocking on the results of the async operation.  You can free up that thread to work on other more productive tasks until the async task has finished and is again productive work.

If your service is not in high demand, and is not frequently in a position where you have more work that needs doing than threads to do it, then you don't need to worry.  For many business apps they simply have so low usage rates that this isn't needed.

If you have a large scale app servicing enough users that you have a very high number of concurrent requests (even if it's just at peak usage times) then it may be work switching to asynchronous counterparts.

Comment: I understood this to be not the service code that he's asking about but rather his client code that submits data to the service and waits for a response. The comment about using async to free up the thread until a response comes in is still valid though - just usually less important on a client side than server. If this was the server, I'd probably go through the effort.